# What is 'fewer than 1 in 10 Americans'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

This is a [source](http://www.geekwire.com/2015/90-of-americans-want-privacy-less-than-10-believe-they-can-get-it/?google_editors_picks=true).

> Nine out of 10 Americans say it’s important to control the information collected about them and who can see it, but ***fewer than 1 in 10 Americans*** are confident that either the government or corporations can provide that control.

What is the meaning of this phrase? Does it mean zero or anything else? Please clarify this phrase. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but I think it's like an approximation so 90% means nine out of 10 also 91%, 92%, 93% or 94% means nine of of 10 and 1%, 2%, 3%, 4%, means 0 or less than 1 in 10 .. if it's 9% then it is less than 1 in 10 .. because 1 in 10 (with no approximation) means exactly 10% ..

Comment: Fewer than 1 in 10 Americans - less than one tenth of Americans - less than 10% of Americans.

Answer (score 2):

Fewer than 1 in 10 Americans simply means less than 10% of Americans.

Comment: ... such as 1 in 20 ...

Answer (score -2):

The problem with "fewer than" is that although it is technically correct, it is not being used any more. What I say is "less than". And I'm a native speaker English teacher. Finally English teachers and experts will just have to accept that people prefer "less than" and we can expect "fewer" to disappear from the language. The process will probably take about ten or twenty more years.

So the specific meaning of the phrase is that "an unstated number which is less than 1% of Americans have this opinion". Usually the exact percentage is known but not given, so it's not an approximation.

Comment: 1 in 10 is 10%, not 1%.

Comment: "Fewer than" is absolutely still used, and in fact is the preferred choice here. In general, "fewer" should be used when referring to countable objects, while "less" should be used with uncountable quantities. "There are fewer apples left today" is correct, "There are less apples left today" is not.

Comment: Sorry I should have said 10%. Matt has stated the rule and he is right that is the rule. What I am saying is that more and more native speakers are rejecting this rule and saying "there are less apples today" . So if you are learning English "fewer" might seem weird as you notice that people don't use it.

Comment: Actually the reverse is true, if ngram viewer is to be believed.  "Less than" was more common than "fewer than" until the 1990's.

Comment: I have searched the Global Web-based English Corpus database (Glowbe) which has 1.9 billion words with the following results

Comment: I have searched the Global Web-based English Corpus database (Glowbe) which has 1.9 billion words with the following results......................  fewer than is used 8881 times per million words and less than is used 173347 times. As I love to tell my students, you can't argue with this. It's not my opinion. This is information technology!!!

Comment: @Matt - But that's exactly the confusion RuchirM is having. If "fewer" is used for countable quantities, when you say "fewer than 1 in 10", the only countable quantity "fewer" than 1 is 0. If you're talking about quantities between 0 and 1 then you're no longer countable, and thus shouldn't you be using "less"? ("One half an apple is fewer than one apple." doesn't sound right.)- The fact that people are countable doesn't really help, because that would mean that we should be saying "fewer than 10% of Americans" instead of "less than 10% of Americans", right?